# How to send a private message to members of a specific role not in a voice channel?

Tags: discord, discord.js

This is the code I use to count members with a specific role whom are in a voice channel. I want to send a private message to members with the role and *not* in a voice channel. How can I do so?

```js
var takaci = 0;
let a = client.guilds
    .get(sunucuid)
    .roles.get(rolid)
    .members.filter(o => o.voiceChannel).size;
let ses = a;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Inverse your predicate function in [`Collection.filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) to acquire only those members with the role and *not* in a voice channel. Use the `!` character, or [logical NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) operator.
2. [Iterate over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) your Collection.
3. Use [`GuildMember.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=send) to send a direct message to each member individually.

```js
const membersToMsg = client.guilds.get(sunucuid).roles.get(rolid).members.filter(m => !m.voiceChannel);

for (const [, member] of membersToMsg) {
  member.send('Hello, world!')
    .catch(console.error); // 'Cannot send messages to this user' is most likely due to privacy settings
}
```

*I'm using a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop in this code rather than [`Map.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) because the latter will simply fire promises and move on, possibly resulting in uncaught rejections.*